# Quick question about a proof a series rearrangement tends to $3$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Find a rearrangement of $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}}$ that converges to $3$

> Solution: Choose $N_1$ s.t. $$1 + \frac 13 + \frac 15 + \ldots + \frac{1}{2N_1 - 1} > 3$$ Next, take enough of the negative terms so that $$\left(1 + \frac 13 + \frac 15 + \ldots + \frac{1}{2N_1 - 1}\right)- \left(\frac 12 + \frac 14 + \frac 16 + \ldots + \frac{1}{2N_2} \right)< 3$$ Now, choose $N_3$ so that it is the first available integer such that  $$\left(1 + \frac 13 + \frac 15 + \ldots + \frac{1}{2N_1 - 1}\right)- \left(\frac 12 + \frac 14 + \frac 16 + \ldots + \frac{1}{2N_2} \right) + \left(\frac{1}{2N_1 + 1} + \frac{1}{2N_1 + 1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2N_3 - 1}\right) > 3$$ We then add in just enough negative terms to make the next sum of $N_3 + N_4$ terms less than $3$, and so on indefinitely. If $X$ is the rearrangement, we want the swinging radius (from one side of $3$ to the other) of the partial sums of $X$ tend to $0$. From $\frac{1}{2N_2}$ onwards, $\color{red}{\text{the difference between a partial sum and $3$ will always be less than the absolute}}\\ \color{red}{\text{ value of the last term}}$ $\frac{1}{2N_k - 1}$ or $\frac{1}{2N_k}$ and we know that this last term tends to $0$ as we go further out along the original series

How do they know the $\color{red}{\text{assertion in red above}}$ holds? I am not sure it's obvious. Having hard time seeing this.

edit: sorry, some text sticking out the margins. Don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Not a great fix, I'm sure there is a better way, although I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea should be that the fractions are decreasing in size, and by design:
$$
\left(1 + \frac 13 + \frac 15 + \ldots + \frac{1}{2N_1 - 1}\right)- \left(\frac 12 + \frac 14 + \frac 16 + \ldots + \frac{1}{2N_2} \right)< 3
$$
is less than $\frac 1{2N_2}$ away from $3$, since $\frac1{2N_2}$ is the exact term that shifted the partial sum from being greater than $3$ to less than $3$.

In the same way, $\frac1{2N_3-1}<\frac1{2N_2}$ will be the exact term that flips the inequality again. And so on.

To put it more succinctly:

> Any number $x-\frac 1n<3$ that has $x>3$ will be at most $\frac1n$ away from $3$. The same goes in the opposite direction.